# Runing code with matlab on the GPU restarts the PC

Tags: matlab, crash, gpu

sometimes when I try to run Matlab code that utilizes the GPU, been with gpuArray or mexcuda the PC restarts, for example this code:

```
n = 5000;
A = single(rand(n,n));

AGPU = gpuArray(A);
t2 = gputimeit(@()(AGPU*AGPU));
```

when n is small there is no problem, but when n = 5000, like in the code above there is a problem.
The GPU is a GeForce GTX 980 Ti, so the problem is not the amount of memory

Comment: You might want to get MATLAB customer service involved. I don't see how anybody here would be able to help you with this.

Comment: What if you push your GPU from another program, e.g. running a GPU benchmark, does it still restart your pc? If not, try and reinstall MATLAB, if that still doesn't work, I would, as Cris says, contact the customer service. If it restarts your pc, the problem is probably in the GPU itself, try and reinstall the GPU driver, if this doesn't work I would contact whoever sold you the PC/GPU